# Button CSS Hyperlink Using DIV

Tags: css, button

I am trying to use below buttons for my web pages. How to use it for setting hyper link in these buttons ?

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');

.preserve-3d {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-smooth: always;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.back {
    width: 33%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 10px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    counter-increment: bc;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.back:before {
    content: counter(bc) "_";
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1260px) {
    .back {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
    .back {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.button_base {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.button_base:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* ### ### ### 01 */
.b01_simple_rollover {
    color: #000000;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.b01_simple_rollover:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* ### ### ### 02 */
.b02_slide_in {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}

.b02_slide_in div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.b02_slide_in div:nth-child(1) {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.b02_slide_in div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: top 0.1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 0.1s ease;
    top: -50px;
}

.b02_slide_in div:nth-child(3) {
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

.b02_slide_in:hover div:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0px;
    transition: top 0.1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 0.1s ease;
}

.b02_slide_in:hover div:nth-child(3) {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease;
}

/* ### ### ### 03 */
.b03_skewed_slide_in {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}

.b03_skewed_slide_in div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

.b03_skewed_slide_in div:nth-child(1) {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.b03_skewed_slide_in div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 230px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform: translate(-250px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-250px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(-250px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
}

.b03_skewed_slide_in div:nth-child(3) {
    color: #ffffff;
    left: -200px;
    transition: left 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.2s ease;
}

.b03_skewed_slide_in:hover div:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transform: translate(-15px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-15px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(-15px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
}

.b03_skewed_slide_in:hover div:nth-child(3) {
    left: 0px;
    transition: left 0.30000000000000004s ease;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.30000000000000004s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.30000000000000004s ease;
}

/* ### ### ### 04 */
.b04_3d_tick {
    perspective: 500px;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    -moz-perspective: 500px;
    perspective-origin: center top;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: center top;
    -moz-perspective-origin: center top;
}

.b04_3d_tick div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}

.b04_3d_tick div:nth-child(1) {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.b04_3d_tick div:nth-child(2) {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
}

.b04_3d_tick:hover div:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.b04_3d_tick:hover div:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

/* ### ### ### 05 */
.b05_3d_roll {
    perspective: 500px;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    -moz-perspective: 500px;
}

.b05_3d_roll div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    pointer-events: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b05_3d_roll div:nth-child(1) {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #000000;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
}

.b05_3d_roll div:nth-child(2) {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -25px;
}

.b05_3d_roll:hover div:nth-child(1) {
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.b05_3d_roll:hover div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

/* ### ### ### 06 */
.b06_3d_swap {
    perspective: 500px;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    -moz-perspective: 500px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
    <div class="button_base b02_slide_in">
        <div>01_Button</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>01_Button</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="back">
    <div class="button_base b03_skewed_slide_in">
        <div>01_Button</div>
        <div></div>
        <div>01_Button</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="back">
    <div class="button_base b04_3d_tick">
        <div>01_Button</div>
        <div>01_Button</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="back">
    <div class="button_base b05_3d_roll">
        <div>02_Button</div>
        <div>01_Button</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use these buttons as link for download button. How to use it for setting hyper link in these buttons ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace button with an a tag and style it like a button, like this:

```
<a href="mylink" class="button-style">01_Button</a>
```

EDIT: Sorry I didn't see you were using divs. Add you link inside the div, like this:

```
<div class="button-style"><a href="mylink">01_Button</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="button_base b02_slide_in">
        <div>01_Button</div>
        <div></div>
        <div><a class="link" href="#">01_Button</a></div>
    </div>

<style>
.link:hover
{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
</style
```